# Karate Mobile - Is there a way in Karate to perform TouchActions or scrollIntoView

Tags: karate

We are exploring Karate for Mobile APP testing. There are some part of the application where we need to scroll drop down to select option or need to use TouchActions to press back button. Is there a way in Karate to implement TouchActions or scrollIntoView.

Thanks,
Shekhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TouchActions` are not supported at this point, but [mobile commands](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) should work from the `develop` branch.

request you to have a look into https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide to build it and verify if it working or should be available on next RC build `0.9.6.RC4`

scrolling using mobile command:

```
script("mobile: scroll", {direction: 'down'} )
```

since you haven't mentioned if it is `Android` or `iOS`, please refer mobile commands page if this is applicable for your driver type

Comment: I have followed the steps you have provided above, however I am getting an error following are the details.

Comment: I have followed the steps you have provided above, however I am getting an error following are the details.   
`Testing on android version 9.0 emulator
 appium version :- 1.17.1
 command :- script("mobile:scroll",{strategy : '-android uiautomator' , selector : "-android.widget.TextView[text='Argentina']"})`
  
`Error:- "Unknown mobile command \"scroll\". Only shell,scrollBackTo,viewportScreenshot,deepLink,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast,acceptAlert,dismissAlert,batteryInfo,deviceInfo,...`

Comment: I have seen an issue as well for same error here https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/issues/867  I tried commands deviceInfo,batteryInfo are working fine.

Comment: ok so you are on `Android` :(. Driver functions that are not implemented can be called using this workaround `https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test#webdriver-tips` .. check if this helps. or else you might have to wait till the implementation is ready in `karate`

Comment: github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1686

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Babu
It works if we use driver.script as below;

driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "strategy" : "accessibility id", "selector": "Lists"})
"Lists" is here its locator.
The only restriction is using limited selector support with this scroll.

Android you can only use: accessibility id, class name, -android uiautomator
iOS you can only use: predicateString